# unable to install psycopg2 due to large error

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 but I keep getting this error:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz (380 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for psycopg2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8vyzoc4h/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8vyzoc4h/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fq16err7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8vyzoc4h/psycopg2/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120002 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:36:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
       36 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8vyzoc4h/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8vyzoc4h/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fq16err7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/include/site/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I can install and use it using psycopg2-binary but I need to install this because it's a dependency (for django-heroku).

I tried installing libpq-dev but got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 12.2-4) but 12.3-1.pgdg20.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

and using sudo apt-get install libpq5

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try installing the library before installing psycopg2 : `sudo apt install libpq-dev`